# Шифрование p2p и безопасность

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, p2p

Я правильно понимаю что обмен ключей происходит по протоколу Диффи-Хеллмана который позволяет обменятся по не защищенному от прослушивания протоколу.

Но получается что если может быть не прослушка, а именно модификация данных то я не могу быть уверенным в том что изначально обменялся ключами именно с своим собеседником, а не с кем то кто мог оказаться по середине?

Т.е. я правильно понимаю что я не могу быть уверенным что мои данные защищены даже если я общаюсь с p2p шифрованием если вдруг кто-то оказался по середине?

Или как это работает, можете подсказать? Можно на примере мессенджеров...

Comment: Вы не указали применительно к какому протоколу шифрования относится вопрос. Если это вдруг SSL то в нем стороны идентифицируют друг друга на основе того, что имеют (как минимум 1 сторона) сертификат, подписанный центром, которому доверяют обе стороны, что исключает mitm атаку

Comment: В случает мессенджеров это ssl ? Т.е. каждое сторона шифрует свой ключ каким то третьим сертификатом или как ?

Comment: Мессенджеры разные. Их разработчики могут использовать любые протоколы, какие им пришли в голову, в том числе и SSL. Это чисто от фантазии их разработчиков зависит откуда они берут сертификаты для клиентов (если вообще используют такую схему шифрования). И если что, корневой сертификат используется только для удостоверения сертификата клиента. Ключ не может шифроваться корневым сертификатом, потому что тогда клиенту придется знать закрытый ключ от него, а тогда грош цена такому сертификату.

Comment: Понятно. Как работает ssl понимаю. я просто пытаюсь понять на любом примере как будет устроено шифрование такое чтобы обе стороны были уверены что их сообщения не прочитают по середине или вобще не изменят. Т.е. я установил с сервером ssl и мой собеседник тоже, мы оба отсылаем до сервера сообщения защищенные но что происходит дальше, т.е. сервер расшифровывает мое сообщение и шифрует его для моего собеседника заново на этапе обмена ключами? Т.е. если сервер захочет прочитать он будет знать наши ключи в итоге?

Comment: Что бы стороны были абсолютно уверены у них должны быть сертификаты, подписанные некоей третьей стороной которой они доверяют. Потому что имея сертификат этой третьей стороны mitm атака проводится элементарно. А это возможно только если обе стороны изначально встретились в одном защищенном помещении, в клетке Фарадея, на одном изолированном от мира компе создали главный сертификат, свои сертификаты, подписали их, заложили свои сертификаты и публичную часть главного в свои средства связи, все остальное надежно удалили.

Comment: Надежность месснждеров в любом случае иллюзия. Стороны могут подписать сертификаты на центральном сервере сети. При этом они должны общаться именно по p2p соединению, минуя тот сервер, который обладает закрытой частью главного сертификата. Это обеспечивает некоторую степень защиты, потому что злоумышленнику надо получить сертификат с того сервера и при этом иметь доступ к одному из маршрутизаторов через который проходит трафик сторон.